# Please explain this Javascript class declaration syntax

Tags: javascript

Please explain how does this syntax actually works in javascript. I know that it somehow define `mod`, but I have never seen `(function(){...})(function(){...})` syntax in javascript before.

```
(function(mod) {
  if (typeof exports == "object" && typeof module == "object") // CommonJS
    module.exports = mod();
  else if (typeof define == "function" && define.amd) // AMD
    return define([], mod);
  else // Plain browser env
    this.Mod = mod();
})(function() { ... } );
```

Comment: That's the universal module definition format: https://github.com/umdjs/umd